What do orange magic abilities mean?
In the Mesmerizer Fangame by Atena, some of the abilities in my Magic menu have names written in orange instead of white. What does it mean when a magic ability is written in orange?


Orange magics are unlockable abilities that were purchased from the Teto Shop or found in a chest. White magics are ones you have access to as soon as you start the game.
Note that three orange abilities from the screenshot in the original post, (Call Doctor, Black Out, and Round Round), are available at the shop in the screenshot below.

Source: I started a new save file on a different PC. I only had access to white magics initially.
